# Schopenhauer: "und selbst Ideen gewissermaßen als Musterformen dastehen"

Tags: word-usage

I am striving with translating an old philosophy text on Schopenhauer:

> Es ist auch aus blinder Notwendigkeit, dass dieser Wille ins Leben hinein will, und so eine erscheinende Welt, eine Welt der Vorstellung entsteht, wo verstandesgemäße Gesetze zu Hause sind, *und selbst Ideen **gewissermaßen** als Musterformen **dastehen***.

How would you rephrase the last sub-sentence

> *und selbst Ideen **gewissermaßen** als Musterformen **dastehen***

in modern German and/or in English?

Comment: That part *is* phrased like in contemporary German. Not the most stylistic, but acceptable.

Comment: *…, and where even ideas in some way stand there as reference shapes.*

Comment: *Musterformen* should probably be translated as *templates* - because that is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use a dictionary?

**[gewissermaßen](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/gewisserma%C3%9Fen)**

- in a manner of speaking
- in a way
- to some extent
- ...

**[dastehen](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/dastehen)**

- to stand there
- to stack up against something/someone = im Vergleich zu etwas/jemanden dastehen
- ...

> und selbst Ideen gewissermaßen als Musterformen dastehen.
>   and even ideas to some extent stand there as role models.

Answer (score 0):

> "Es ist auch aus blinder Notwendigkeit, dass dieser Wille ins Leben hinein 
>   will, 
>   und so eine erscheinende Welt, eine Welt der Vorstellung entsteht, 
>   wo verstandesgemäße Gesetze zu Hause sind, und selbst Ideen 
>   gewissermaßen als Musterformen dastehen."

My translation:

> "It is also out of absolute necessity for this will to enter into life, 
>   and thus creating a emerging world, a world of imagination, where 
>   rational laws are at home, and even ideas stand in the capacity of 
>   patterns in a manner of speaking."

Maybe it would be better to unpick this long and complicated sentence into 2 or 3 shorter ones?